# What is the code for the martianbuddy.com cabinet in Doom 3 BFG Edition?

Tags: doom-3-bfg-edition

In Doom 3 BFG there are the same two cabinets as in the original Doom 3 which can only be opened by a code from martianbuddy.com. This website just redirects to bethesda now and the code cannot be obtained.

**What is the code for those cabinets?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both cabinets are opened by the code 0508. The one in Administration will contain a Chaingun and the one in Delta Labs 2B will contain the BFG 9000.

Comment: Incidentally, this code is in the subject of the email sent to Jonathan A. Moses telling him that he won.